# Пишу бота на языке Python. Нужна помощь с БД

Tags: python, файлы, telebot

В общем, нужно что бы пользователь когда писал типо /start, в самом начале, его сразу записывало в базу (сама база из себя представляет .txt файл), сохранялось всё, и с новым пользователем было тоже самое, но что бы он записывался на следующую строку БД. Я уже понял как записывать самого пользователя в бд, но если приходит новый пользователь, то старый стирается, и вместо него пишет нового. Что делать? Надо еще желательно, что бы бот умел читать данный документ, и искать в документе id пользователя, выдавать ему результат. Вот сама часть кода:

```
lines = [f'{message.from_user.id}']
f = open('DB balance jopa.txt', 'w')
with open("DB balance jopa.txt", "w") as file:
for line in lines:
file.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: Мне кажется в этом случае было бы гораздо удобнее использовать настоящую БД и соответствующие инструменты вставки/выборки данных. Вам же будет легче потом искать данные о пользователях (если конечно вам вообще нужно данные получать, если же это что-то вроде логов, то и *txt* подойдёт). Вот вам небольшая [статья по SQL](https://habr.com/ru/post/480838/), с интеграцией в питон разберетесь.

Comment: Вернитесь, пожалуйста, к [основам работы с файлами в Python](https://tproger.ru/articles/files-in-python/). А потом уже стройте планы о собственных ботах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что делать?  -  В первую очередь читать учебник по Python. Раздел "работа с файлами". Где на первой же странице написано, что ДОПИСЫВАТЬ что-то в существеющий файл надо задать метод доступа "a" (а не "w")